# Using database values in php function

Tags: php, database, variables

I'm quite new to PHP and not familiar at all with using databases, so bear with me if you can. I have a site filled with comparison tables that basically have **3 values per product**:

```
$product + $delivery = 'price'
```

I'm familiar with making a simple function that sums and echos the variables, but I want something more specific.

Basically, for `$product`, I want to set the value on-page, but for `$delivery`, I want to pull the variable value from some sort of database, so it sort of looks like:

```
$15.00 + $delivery_company_one = 'price'
```

How would I go about doing this? What should I specifically look into and learn? 
Any references would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should learn basic PHP syntax. You can't say:

```
$var1 + $var2 = $var3;
```

PHP won't work like that. The leftside variable is assigned to the value of the rightside, but `$var1 + $var2` is not a variable, nor something that can be defined.

If you want to learn how to pull things from a database, you should definitely look into an `SQL` database, possibly accessing it through `PDO`. This means that you'd have to learn `OOP`. You can search for all of these things using Google. **Skip the result that has a URL of w3schools.com/* for best results.**

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I know $var1 + $var2 is not proper syntax, I was just displaying it like that to get across what I'm trying to do in the least characters possible.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to go through a couple MySQL tutorials. MySQL is a widely used and supported database that is fairly simple to start with but has extremely advanced and powerful features once you progress along.

Play around with the XAMPP stack for a quick start.
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Start with some MySQL tutorials to get an idea of how that works.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners/

Try to access it through PHP and PDO.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score -1):

Google search returns a tutorial http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65 to teach you how to use php using the mysqli

DONT USE MYSQL!!!!! use mysqli

Hire me chacha